# Problem in SQL AND WHERE second condition works, first doesn't

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a query as follow

```
SELECT *
FROM blogs
WHERE (status = 1 AND trash = 0)
  AND (url LIKE '%searchString%' OR metaTitle LIKE '%searchString%');
```

For some reason the first condition doesn't work but the second condition works. I get the results according the search but the status and trash flags aren't working.

Comment: and do you have rows where  `(status = 1 AND trash = 0) AND (url LIKE '%searchString%' OR metaTitle LIKE '%searchString%');`? Have you found results in your MySQL client or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Can you please provide a data set and indicate the data that is output (or working) and vice versa?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE (`status` = 1 AND `trash` = 0) AND (`url` LIKE '%blog%') this is what i tested and found working in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the () around this:  (status = 1 AND trash = 0).
If status = 0 and trash = 1, this would resolve to true if you have brackets around it. Give it a go.

Comment: No, this is still exactly the same logic as before.

Answer (score 1):

Do this when type Where....

```
WHERE status ='1' AND trash ='0' AND (url LIKE '%searchString%' OR metaTitle LIKE '%searchString%');
```

It's May Be Work.... Cause You Have Work Three `AND` So define firs `AND` then Do your `LIKE` into Brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
SELECT *
FROM blogs
WHERE status = 1 AND trash = 0 AND
      (url LIKE '%searchString%' OR metaTitle LIKE '%searchString%');
```

Comment: I am missing how this is different from the OP's query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Closing brackets in first and condition

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE status = 1 AND trash = 0 AND (url LIKE '%searchString%' OR metaTitle LIKE '%searchString%');
```

Comment: No, this is still exactly the same logic as before.

Comment: Try this one 
->SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE  (url LIKE '%searchString%' OR metaTitle LIKE '%searchString%') AND status = 1 AND trash = 0;

Comment: You can arrange those ANDed conditions in any order (of course keeping the `OR` in brackets) with any number of brackets, it't still the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some NULL Value in those fields

```
SELECT *
FROM blogs
WHERE (status = 1 AND trash = 0)
  AND (isnull(url,'') LIKE '%searchString%' OR isnull(metaTitle,'') LIKE '%searchString%');
```